# How does cron internally schedule jobs?

Tags: linux, unix, cron, scheduler

How do "modern" `cron` daemons *internally* schedule their jobs?  Some `crond`s used to schedule a run every so often via `at`.  So after a crontab is written out, does `crond`:

1. Parse the crontab for all future events and the sleep for the intervals?
2. Poll an aggregated crontab database every minute to determine if the current time matches the schedule pattern?
3. Other?

Thanks,

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A few crickets heard in this question.  Good 'ol RTFC with some discrete event simulation papers and Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Multi-user_capability

> The algorithm used by this cron is as
>   follows:
>
> 1. On start-up, look for a file named .crontab in the home directories of
>      all account holders.
> 2. For each crontab file found, determine the next time in the future
>      that each command is to be run.
> 3. Place those commands on the Franta-Maly event list with their
>      corresponding time and their "five
>      field" time specifier.
> 4. Enter main loop:
>
>    1. Examine the task entry at the head of the queue, compute how far in the
>         future it is to be run.
>    2. Sleep for that period of time.
>    3. On awakening and after verifying the correct time, execute the task at
>         the head of the queue (in background)
>         with the privileges of the user who
>         created it.
>    4. Determine the next time in the future to run this command and place
>         it back on the event list at that time

Comment: Based on the `man` page for `cron`, it looks like it wakes up every minute to check if it should run a job: "cron then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking each command to see if it should be run in the current minute."  This is from Vixie Cron which came installed on Debian (written by Paul Vixie).  I think the algorithm you described was used when waking up every minute was too costly.

Comment: I wish I could find a description of a franta-maly event list somewhere online. Is this a common data structure?

Comment: @TylerBrock, I believe OP is referring to Franta, W. R., and Kurt Maly. An Efficient Data Structure for the Simulation Event Set. University of Minnesota, http://staff.ii.pw.edu.pl/~gjb/aal/index_lists.pdf.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @AaronBlenkush! Been trying to answer that question for a while now.

Comment: How does the sleeping work internally? I mean, how does the computer know that something has waited for X milliseconds and that now is the time to start doing things?

Comment: @ifly6 the short oversimplified answer is that a process can tell the kernel's process scheduler to wake it up after a certain amount of time. The process scheduler uses the CPU's hardware to keep track of time.  There is of course way more to process scheduling than will fit in a comment.

Comment: But imagine that during step 4.1, if the next task is supposed to run after an hour, cron will go to sleep for an hour. But while its sleeping, a new task is added which is supposed to run every minute. How will it handle such case?

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi when a user edits the crontab file, the crond demon is restarted and the algorithm goes back to step 1.

Comment: But then the timer for all jobs would be reset everytime crontab is reset?

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a [blog post](https://anmolsinghjaggi.com/2020/05/09/writing-your-own-cron-service/) describing it.
which contains **my thoughts** on how to implement task scheduling utilities like [Cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [Quartz](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz).

Quoting the relevant text from there:

- We can have a finite thread-pool which will execute all the tasks by picking them up from a `PriorityBlockingQueue` (thread-safe heap) prioritized on `job.nextExecutionTime()`.
- Meaning that the top element of this heap will be always be the one that will fire the soonest.
- We will be following the standard threadpool producer-consumer pattern.
- We will have one thread which will be running in an infinite loop and submitting new jobs to the thread pool after consuming them from the queue.
  Lets call it **QueueConsumerThread**:

```java
void goToSleep(job, jobQueue){
    jobQueue.push(job);
    sleep(job.nextExecutionTime() - getCurrentTime());
}

void executeJob(job, jobQueue){
    threadpool.submit(job); // async call
    if (job.isRecurring()) {
        job = job.copy().setNextExecutionTime(getCurrentTime() + job.getRecurringInterval());
        jobQueue.add(job);
    }
}

@Override
void run(){
    while(true)
    {
        job = jobQueue.pop()
        if(job.nextExecutionTime() > getCurrentTime()){
            // Nothing to do
            goToSleep(job, jobQueue)
        }
        else{
            executeJob(job, jobQueue)
        }
    }
}
```

- There will be one more thread which will be monitoring the crontab file for any new job additions and will push them to the queue.
- Lets call it **QueueProducerThread**:

```java
@Override
void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        newJob = getNewJobFromCrontabFile() // blocking call
        jobQueue.push(newJob)
    }
}
```

- However, there is a problem with this:

  - Imagine that Thread1 is sleeping and will wake up after an hour.
  - Meanwhile a new task arrives which is supposed to run every minute.
  - This new task will not be able to start executing until an hour later.
- To solve this problem, we can have ProducerThread wakeup ConsumerThread from its sleep forcefully whenever the new task has to run sooner than the front task in the queue:

```java
@Override
void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        newJob = getNewJobFromCrontabFile() // blocking call
        jobQueue.push(newJob)
        if(newJob == jobQueue.peek())
        {
            // The new job is the one that will be scheduled next.
            // So wakeup consumer thread so that it does not oversleep.
            consumerThread.interrupt()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this might not be how cron is implemented internally.
However, this is the most optimal solution that I can think of.
It requires no polling and all threads sleep until they need to do any work.

Comment: Right, but how getNextExecutionTime works? I'm trying to figure out how does it merge all these schedules to get the next time and I cannot tell.

Comment: The intial value of `nextExecutionTime` will have to parsed from the cron string. For instance, if cron string says that the job should be executed every 10 minutes, then when we read this from the cron file, we will set the next execution time to `currentTime + 10 minutes`.
Since its a recurring job, after the first run, a new job will be created with the next closest execution time: `job = job.copy().setNextExecutionTime(getCurrentTime() + job.getRecurringInterval());`