# Cron unexpected behaviour when date changes

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I've a cron instance executing in a embedded device in a ELINOS4 environment. This device have a problem, I think related to battery, which changes the system date.

For the embedded application is not a problem because the app resynchornize the date. But for cron daemon affects its scheduler causing to programm next execution far in the future. Executing cron with flags I get this logs:

```
[3933] TargetTime=1359121500, sec-to-wait=60
...
[3933] spool dir mtime unch, no load needed.
[3933] tick(45,13,24,0,5) user [root:0:0:...] cmd="/etc/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf"
[3933] TargetTime=1359121560, sec-to-wait=1130199663
[3933] sleeping for 1130199663 seconds
```

I've tried to change manually the date, but cron doesn't detect this change (it's sleeping https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141239).

One quick hack is to modify the source code of cron, but does a better solution exist?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious "fix your hardware", the immediate suggestion would be to have a daemon that checks the time, and if it sees it jump back (or forward?) more than a few seconds, restart crond (and any other process that may use this sort of method to determine "next time to wake up").