# REST APIs job scheduling

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I have a backend system which is collection of multiple rest APIs. There is one API which I want to automate i.e. the API should be triggered daily on a particular time like 11 AM.

I am using **`Jersey-2.0`** on `tomcat`. Services uses AWS-DynamoDB, SNS, SES.

Does AWS have a scheduler which can invoke the API endpoint?

OR

Can I use the same EC2-instance for triggering the API on which the tomcat is hosted?

Comment: You can use [CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) to execute lambda function on regular basis which will trigger your api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on a Schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) or a [cron, not corn :) job](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) on your EC2 instance.

Comment: Are corn jobs busy waiting?

Comment: corn jobs? Did you mean to say CRON jobs?

Comment: Yes, Are CRON jobs busy waiting?

Comment: Here is a good background on how exactly Cron jobs operate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4141239/5535604 so if you are concerned about cpu and memory consumption of the idle Cron jobs - don't worry. They don't.