# What is a Franta-Maly event list?

Tags: algorithm, cron

The top answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982957/how-does-cron-internally-schedule-jobs) question references a Franta-Maly event list. What is a Franta-Maly event list and what are its use cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **Franta-Maly event list** (or event set) was described in a [1977 paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359763.359801) by W.R. Franta and Kurt Maly, *An Efficient Data Structure for the Simulation Event Set*. In this paper, they presented a new event scheduling algorithm that improves on previously published algorithms. According to the abstract:

> First, the new algorithm's performance is quite insensitive to skewed
> distributions, and second, its worst-case complexity is O(sqrt(n)),
> where n is the number of events in the set. Furthermore, tests
> conducted to estimate the average complexity showed it to be nearly
> independent of n.

The paper presents what the authors call a TL (two-level) algorithm for inserting an event into the event set:

> Stripped of its simulation terminology, we require an efficient
> solution to the following problem: devise a physical data structure
> for a *dynamically changing* collection of records which supports
> retrieval of the record with the minimally valued key. In the
> simulation environment, the records are event notices, each containing
> information identifying an event, and the key is the scheduled time
> for its occurrence. The scheduled time is known as the event time, and
> the collector<sup>1</sup> of records is called the **event set**.
>
> ...
>
> The basic idea of the TL algorithm is to limit the number of notices
> which must be scanned for an insertion. This requirement is met by
> dynamically creating for each interval a list of secondary keys and
> associating them with the right boundary dummy key. Each secondary key
> points to the beginning of a sublist of notices within an interval...
> Whenever one of these sublists becomes unbalanced, i.e. too large, the
> structure is adjusted by either moving the notice to the adjacent list
> or creating a new sublist with its associated secondary key.

<sup>1 I would like to suggest that perhaps "collector of records" is a typo in the original paper, and that "collection of records" may be what was intended here.</sup>

Link to the Franta-Maly paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359763.359801

---

<sup>Note: The quoted sections of this answer are subject to the following copyright notice:</sup>

> <sup>Communications of the ACM, August 1977, Volume 20, Number 8.
> Copyright (c) 1977, Association for Computing Machinery, Inc. General
> permission to republish, but not for profit, all or part of this
> material is granted provided that ACM's copyright notice is given and
> that reference is made to the publication, to its date of issue, and
> to the fact that reprinting privileges were granted by permission of
> the Association for Computing Machinery. Authors' address: Department
> of Computer Science, University of Minnesota, Minneapolis, MN 55455.</sup>

Comment: The link is not accessible. I found another from ACM. https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/359763.359801

Comment: @FranzWong: Thanks, I updated my answer to use your link.